# Server Stops Responding when Bandwidth is used

Tags: networking, ssh

All SSH sessions close randomly on my Ubuntu 16.04 server. It seems that whenever too much bandwidth is used (e.g. using uttorent, many people on minecraft server) all connections close.

The only thing that allows me to connect via putty is a hard reset. I don't know the exact cause or where I should even be looking to diagnose this problem.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How much RAM? How much Swap Space? If you have finite RAM, and no swap, processes will die randomly.